# Xcode Error "Couldn’t load the next page."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

It's really not my day, I was about to create a new class in Xcode (Version 3.1.4) so I went to (right click) Add > New File... selected Objective-C Class and i got the message "Couldn’t load the next page.". Anyone?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just changed the drop-down box that especifies the inheritance of the class and it "found" the next page... :S